# sql Better way than intersection of inner-join

Tags: mysql, sql, intersection, self-join

We have a table of 2 columns : ObjectName and ObjectColor. It is a many to many table. And we have a given set of colors {x, y, z,...}

We want to select the list of ObjectName that exists with all those given colors.

if we have N colors, I can imagine an sql query with N-1 intersection on this same table. Or we can also imagine N-1 self-joins on that table.

Is there a better solution ?
Is there a particular solution with MySQL ?

THINKS

Comment: If the colours are rows in a table at runtime, learn about relational division and similar queries.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one method:

```
select objectname
from t
where objectcolor in (x, y, z)
group by objectname
having count(*) = 3;
```

You need to adjust the "3" to match the size of the list.

Comment: Nice! And for the "3", I can do that. I think that this solution is much better than intersection or join. 
Don't you think that the "count(*)" can sometimes be expensive?

Comment: The `COUNT(*)` will require a table or index scan, but I'm not sure how you're going to avoid that.